# Enumeration types in Node.js native addon

Tags: c++, node.js, enums, v8

Is it possible to create some `enum` in C++ code of Node.js addon and then expose this type to js code? I found that native enum types exist in js, but there's no information about their implementation in v8 engine.

Comment: It appears that ain't no way for legitimate enums for node.js addon. In Node.js Google group I got the following answer to the question:
"Nothing you can do about that.  Export them [parameters] as integers and check your 
inputs in C++ land."

Answer (score 4):

Note that in the example given by [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746580/kevin) you need to create an instance of `Local<Object>` before using it so make sure you call `Object::New()`.

```
Local<Object> obj = Object::New();
const char* k = "HEADERS_RECEIVED";
int v = 1;
obj->Set(v8::String::NewSymbol(k), v8::Int32::New(v), ReadOnly); // Use PropertyAttribute ReadOnly so that value won't be changed by javascript.
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific enum types in javascript, instead use constant int for that, such as in web, properties `UNSENT,OPENED, HEADERS_RECEIVED,LOADING,DONE` of `XMLHttpRequest` are defined as enum type in C++. To export these properties in v8 for javascript, use like:

```
Local<Object> obj;
const char* k = "HEADERS_RECEIVED";
int v = 1;
obj->Set(v8::String::NewSymbol(k), v8::Int32::New(v), ReadOnly); // Use PropertyAttribute ReadOnly so that value won't be changed by javascript.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is has changed now according to latest [v8 API ref](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-7.2/db/d85/classv8_1_1_object.html#a6f76b2ed605cb8f9185b92de0033a820)

```
Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
Local<Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();
Local<Object> obj;
obj->DefineOwnProperty(
                       context,
                       String::NewFromUtf8(isolate,"enum"),
                       Number::New(isolate,1), v8::ReadOnly
                       );
```